# Wrap Translator `trans` and `transChoice` function output into span

Tags: symfony, twig

Translation works fine for Symfony project, but to improve the translation process for the translator I'd like to wrap all translations in a span with the `translatable` class:

```
// View
<li>{{ 'main.translation_key'|trans }}</li>
```

or

```
// Controller
echo '<li>'.$this->get('translator')->trans('main.translation_key').'</li>';
```

This currently just outputs:

```
<li>Known translation value</li>
```

But I'd like to wrap it in `<span>` for some specific environments. Let's say we have a `TRANS` environment in our Symfony application. For that environment I'd like the output to be:

```
<li>
    <span class="translatable" data-translation-key="main.translation_key">
        Known translation value
    </span>
</li>
```

Why shoud I like that? This allows me to write a Javascript implementation against it for a specific environment. We can then experiment with http://createjs.org/ for translating directly from the view.

So, does the Translator allow me to easily override the `trans` and `transChoice` functions? Or can this be implemented in another way? This does not only apply to Twig, because we also do translations in Controller and Command classes.